# only second audio plays on array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I declared `ar` array variable and added my two audios inside but when I hit `.play` only second element into array plays. any solutions ?

```
<button class="play"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
```

```js
var playthis = new Audio();
var trench01 = 'songs/example1.m4a';
var trench03 = 'songs/example2.mp3';
var ar = [trench01, trench03]
playthis.src = ar[0 , 1]

$('.play').click(function(){
  playthis.play();
})
```

Comment: `ar[0 , 1]` is just the same as `ar[1]`, hence it's the expected behavior. If you want to play both, you need to loop the array.

Comment: @briosheje Can you help how

Comment: @Marcus did it, I was expecting someone to actually answer, since I don't feel this question falls in the typographical error, but rather on a conceptual one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the meaning of the comma operator in javascript arrays (in that scenario specifically):

```
ar[0 , 1]
```

is equivalent to:

```
ar[1]
```

So, only the last element is played, because in fact you are selecting binding to the `src` property of the audio object the last element of the array, which is "songs/example2.mp3" or, really, `trench03`.

If you want to play both, you need to first create an Audio object for each of them, set the `src` attribute and loop them on click, by executing the `play` method of each:

```
var trench01 = 'songs/example1.m4a';
var trench03 = 'songs/example2.mp3';
var ar = [trench01, trench03];
var tracks = ar.map((trench) => {
   var audio = new Audio();
   audio.src = trench;
   return audio;
});
$('.play').click(function(){
    tracks.forEach(track => track.play());
})
```