# on click to move on next variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I move from one variable called `trench1` to `trench2` with click I made this code but not working

```
var playthis = new Audio();
var trench1 = 'songs/example1.m4a';
var trench2 = 'songs/example2.m4a';
var trench3 = 'songs/example3.mp3';
i = 0;
$('.next').click(function(){
    playthis.src = trench + i++;
})
```

```html
<button class="next"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></button>
```

Comment: Use an array of songs rather than individual variables and increment the array index

Comment: something like this `playthis.src = window[\`trench${++i}\`];`

Comment: Wait a second, that's way too similar to this one I just answered this morning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373512/only-second-audio-plays-on-array/57373609 Weren't you looking for arrays?

Comment: @BrettGregson wait, it's different, I'm just wondering why it's so similar.

Comment: @briosheje probably homework :P

Comment: yeah its homework :( summer is lost...

Comment: @Levancho Your teacher should really be aware that you're missing something, then. I would recommend to you and your mate to have a deeper look at how arrays works and javascript works in general and hope you will learn something useful from the answers given ;).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use an array.

```js
var trenches = [trench1, trench2, trench3];
var current_trench = 0;

$('.next').click(function() {
  playthis.src = trenches[current_trench++];
  if (current_trench >= trenches.length) current_trench = 0;
});
```

Comment: I put it in an ```if``` statement for clarity. Getting modulo involved can be confusing for novices.